# Swift SFSpeechRecognizer not working twice

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

This is my first time using SFSpeechRecognizer in Swift and one piece of functionality isn't working. When I press the button `audioButtonPressed`, it seems to start recognition fine, and pressing it again stops it. When I try pressing it again to start recognition again, the recognition doesnt work and leaves me with a blank text view. How should I do this?

Here's my code

```
@IBAction func audioButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if isRecording {
        stopRecording()
        delegate?.speechRecognitionComplete(query: query)
        audioButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        isRecording = false
    } else {
        startRecording()
        audioButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        isRecording = true
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    recognitionRequest = nil
    recognitionTask = nil
}

func startRecording() {
    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        return
    }
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        var isFinal = false
        if result != nil {
            self.query = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.audioTextField.text = self.query
            isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
        }
        if error != nil || isFinal {
            self.stopRecording()
        }
    })
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("the audio session isn't configured correctly")
    }
    let recordingFormat = audioEngine.inputNode?.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    audioEngine.inputNode?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, time) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
        audioTextField.text = "How may I help you"
    } catch {
        print("audio engine failed to start")
    }
}
```

When i first press audiobutton, start recording is called and it works perfectly, pressing it again stop recording is called and works fine, but then pressing again does not make the recognition start again.... ideas?

Comment: your method `startRecording ` will be called again when you press start recording button at second time ?

Comment: in my case, when you want to stop record / play this code worked: self.audioEngine.stop() inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0) self.recognitionRequest = nil self.recognitionTask = nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing `recognitionTask.cancel()` before you dealloc task in stopRecording function.

Comment: Thank you for posting this Piotr.   Just saved me a ton of trial and error.